# why does this jquery image swap not work in chrome and on first load in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery to replace an image on rollover (with fade) you can see this on the bottom left here:

http://www.anzie.com/index_rollover.php

However in chrome it just fades to near opaque. and in firefox on the first load I get a small blue box on the top left corner (as if it is out of position). but then on refresh it works in firefox. This is working perfectly on my own machine, it only does not work when I try it online. Which leads me to thing it is not loading the images in time perhaps? I am not sure what to do..

Here is my php:

```
<a  href="<?php echo tep_href_link(FILENAME_EVENTS); ?>"><img src="images/home_buttons/water_bag.jpg" alt="watch la vie en couleur"   border="0" align="left" hoverImg="images/home_buttons/water_bag-hover.jpg" /></a>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

$('body').find('*[hoverImg]').each(function(index){
    $this = $(this)
    $this.wrap('<div>')     
    $this.parent().css('width',$this.width())  
    $this.parent().css('height',$this.height())
    $this.parent().css('background-image',"url(" + $this.attr('hoverImg')+")")
        $this.hover(function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',.01)    
        },function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',1)             
        })                    
});


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I right click in chrome and say "Inspect"; your height/width are set to 0px. If I inline edit your height/width via chromes tools the image appears.    Try jquery's outerWidth() and see if that provides better results.

http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: Well I didnt have the domensions of the image set in the html. Soo I'm pretty sure that fixed it. So thanks!

Comment: I think your script is almost spot on, just a div styling issue (works in IE).  Throw your height/width into vars and debug it via chrome.  :)

Comment: I cannot take any credit for the script. It was given to me in a previous question by @Diodeus

Answer (score 2):

Try calling your code in

```
$(document).load( ... )
```

instead. Images aren't ready in `ready`. Load is a callback for anything with a src attribute. So once all those load (including images) it will fire. You can also call it on images. For example

```
$('img').load( function() ... );
```

Method chaining for performance.

```
$('body').find('*[hoverImg]').each(function(index){
  $this = $(this)
  $this.wrap('<div>')     
       .parent()
              .css('width',$this.width())  
              .css('height',$this.height())
              .css('background-image',"url(" + $this.attr('hoverImg')+")")
        .end()
        .hover(function() {
          $(this).stop()
          $(this).fadeTo('',.01)    
         },function() {
            $(this).stop()
            $(this).fadeTo('',1)             
         })                    
});
```

Comment: all I did was change the .ready to .load and now it doesnt seem to fire at all: http://bit.ly/zFNYVL

Comment: @Sackling - odd. Try declaring your js in the head instead of inline.

Comment: Ahh, combined with Brian's observation I think I see what is wrong and also why my solution failed for you. So in your first example the image hasn't loaded yet, so the element has no height and width when you set $(this).parent().css('width') is zero! Now when you switched it to load it fixes it, except that since you declared your js inline, the image will actually load sometimes, causing the `load` event to never fire! Catch 22 indeed. Move the js into your head and use the code I provided and it short sort it. Alternately, set the parent's height width on hover instead.

Comment: Also, use method chaining to improve performance. See my updated answer.

Comment: sweet makes sense. I'm using Brian's solution and keeping the JS inline for now because it is only used on this page and my head is a php include on every page (I maybe should change that).. But It is good to know about .load for the future as well so thank you.